# jQuery Add() not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build up a jQuery set using add() but my implementation is not adding elements to the set.

```
 var questionPath = $(); // create empty set
    var selectedRuleElement = $(event.currentTarget);
    questionPath.add(selectedRuleElement); //no element is added to set here!
    selectedRuleElement.find('li.property-value-node').each(function () {
        var questionId = $(this).attr('data-parent-id');
        questionPath.add($('#' + questionId)); // or here!
    });
    return questionPath;
```

Both of the above add() lines are given a valid element as an argument. Can someone tell me the correct way to add elements to a jQuery set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like strings, jQuery objects are immutable, so you need to re-assign the returned value. Otherwise you're discarding the value returned by `.add()` and `questionPath` remains unaltered.

```
questionPath = questionPath.add(selectedRuleElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**jQuery.merge()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/):

```
var questionPath = $(); // create empty set
var selectedRuleElement = $(event.currentTarget);
$.merge(questionPath,selectedRuleElement);  //merging
selectedRuleElement.find('li.property-value-node').each(function () {
    var questionId = $(this).attr('data-parent-id');
    $.merge(questionPath,$('#' + questionId)); //merging
});
return questionPath;
```

Comment: Eh, not so much. `$.merge` is really meant for arrays, not jQuery objects (which are array-likes).